# How to preload image offscreen and then move to different onscreen element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm building a website/app that will display six different images at a time. The contents of those images are loaded from another site and changing regularly. Where any particular image goes on screen depends on the state of all images already on screen.

To get the image I use jQuery to change the `src` attribute of one of the 6 `img` locations, then wait for the load using jQuery `load()`, then show it. However, this means I have to pick my location *before* the image is loaded. The problem I'm having is that between the time I initiate the load and when the image finally does load, the proper location for that image might have changed.

So my question is whether there's a way to load the image offscreen (say in a hidden `img`), and then, when it's loaded, get a notification of it being finished and then *move* that image to the correct location at that moment.

I've found lots of preload questions and answers on StackOverflow, but they all presume you know where you want the image to go when you initiate the load.

Update: thinking more on this question, perhaps another way of framing it is 1) if I load an image from an offsite server into an offscreen/hidden `img` and wait for it to load, 2) would subsequently setting the `src` attribute of an onscreen/visible `img` to the *same image URL* draw from the server or the browser cache? In other words, if I load a remote image offscreen does the next request for that same image go back to the server or to the browser cache (and would this be consistent for all browsers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Way to do it:

```js
function loadImg(url, callback, key) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    callback(image, key)
  };
  image.onerror = function() {};
  image.src = url;
}

function imageOnload(image, key) {
  imageGoesTo[key].src = image.src
}

var imageGoesTo = {
  "firstPicture": document.getElementById("img1"),
  "secondPicture": document.getElementById("img2"),
}

loadImg("http://7pi.azurewebsites.net/img/DSC09906.jpg", imageOnload, "firstPicture")
imageGoesTo["secondPicture"] = document.getElementById("img3")
loadImg("http://7pi.azurewebsites.net/img/DSC07934.jpg", imageOnload, "secondPicture")
```

```html
<img id="img1" alt="loading">
<img id="img2" alt="loading">
<img id="img3" alt="loading">
```